# On the web, how do you make the code be highlighted as the user is typing it? I only managed to make it that the code is highlighted on button click

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

In my [PicoBlaze Simulator in JavaScript](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze.html), I managed to program that, when the user presses the button "*Highlight Assembly*", the assembly code is highlighted. But the cursor is then moved to the beginning of the assembly program. How could I make it so that the assembly code is highlighted *as the user is typing it*?

I have tried it this way:
In the [`footerscript.js`](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/blob/c62ed83a05ebb5adb5d11e312ea3fc6569403302/footerScript.js#L2) I added the following (and I commented it out when I realized it isn't working):

```js
// For now, attempting to highlight code as the user is typing is worse
// than useless, because it moves the cursor to the beginning.
/*
document.getElementById("assemblyCode").
       oninput=syntaxHighlighter;
*/
```

In the [`headerScript.js`](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/blob/c62ed83a05ebb5adb5d11e312ea3fc6569403302/headerScript.js#L121) file, I added the following code at the beginning of the `syntaxHighlighter` function:

```js
function syntaxHighlighter(/*edit*/) {
  //"edit" should contain the
  // cursor position, but that
  // seems not to work.
  if (areWeHighlighting)
    return;
  areWeHighlighting = true;
  const assemblyCodeDiv = document.getElementById("assemblyCode");
  const assemblyCode = assemblyCodeDiv.innerText.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                           .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                           .replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  // const start=edit.selectionStart,
  //  end=edit.selectionEnd; //Cursor position.
```

And, at [the end of the `syntaxHighlighter` function, in that same file](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/blob/c62ed83a05ebb5adb5d11e312ea3fc6569403302/headerScript.js#L197), I added the following:

```js
  assemblyCodeDiv.innerHTML = highlightedText;
  // The following code is supposed to move the cursor to the correct
  // position, but it doesn't work.
  /*
  const range=document.createRange();
  range.setStart(assemblyCodeDiv,start);
  range.setEnd(assemblyCodeDiv,end);
  const selection=window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  */
```

However, that's not working, so I commented it out. Why doesn't it work? How do I make it work?

It is important to me that my PicoBlaze Simulator continues working in Firefox 52 (the last version of Firefox to work on Windows XP), as many computers at my university run Windows XP and use Firefox 52 as the browser.

Comment: This could be tricky - modifying the `innerText` of a focused element moves the text cursor to index 0.

Comment: @GershomMaes I know, which is the whole reason I added [the code for moving the cursor to the correct position](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/PicoBlaze_Simulator_in_JS/blob/c62ed83a05ebb5adb5d11e312ea3fc6569403302/headerScript.js#L197), which is also in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guess that it must be extremely hard to calculate the same caret position in highlighted content (that contains additional mark-up) precisely by using the position taken from the raw content.

**I'll suggest a little hacky but effective alternative:**

Create an overlay element looks like the one you are using to enter the code, and display the highlighted text on that. Hide the text on the first element so the user will see only highlighted & overlayed content. Second element will have `pointer-events: none;` so will be transparent to the mouse events. Only caret will be visible in the first element.

*Please note that for this solution to work perfectly there must be nothing but the color difference between the rendered versions of highlighted and non-highlighted code.*

**Here are the steps on how to do it:**

- Let's call the first element `assemblyCode`
- Create a second element named `assemblyCodeOverlay` that will have all the styles the first element has and place it on top of it (it must be next in the DOM).
- Add some more styling to the first one:

  `color: transparent;`

  `caret-color: black;`

*This will hide the text while keeping the caret visible.*

- Add some more styling to the second one:

  `pointer-events: none;`

  `background: transparent;`

*This will make the overlay element transparent for the caret underneath and also transparent to the mouse events.*

- Run syntaxHighlighter on each keydown event fires on the first one
- Adjust scrollTop of the overlay element on each scroll event fires on the first
- syntaxHighlighter will take the content from the first element and will set the content of the overlay

[image: monospaced font example]

Comment: > *Please note that for this solution to work perfectly there must be nothing but the color difference between the rendered versions of highlighted and non-highlighted code.*

Hmm... I don't think your solution will work then, since I am using bold and italic in my syntax highlighting.

Comment: Not really in your case. Looks like monospaced font you are using has fixed width for bold and italic characters too. Check the screen record.